# TableViewCell Title not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, cell, title

My `UITableCell` title in my `viewController` is not showing.

What's wrong with it?

I've dragged the `TableView` and `TableViewCell` on it but it doesn't show, it stays white.

Screenshot: https://blazor.nl/uploads/get/19d2ed8a2662039e1104474b0426f2e0/IMG-0286

I have used below code

```
-(void) arraySetup{
    imageNameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"image1", @"image2", @"image3", @"image4"]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return imageNameArray.count;
}

#pragma mark - UITableView DataSource Methods
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    return cell;
}
```

Please advice me how to do it?

Comment: Did you connect the delegate and datasource?

Comment: Yes I did. The tabel and its cell is by the way in a second view controller.

Comment: can you please post your code so it'll better for quick lookup into the matter

Comment: where you exactly want the title on header or in cell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's obvious, because you're dequeuing a table view cell (that's, basically, **a template**), but you're not filling it with data. So:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"cell";

    // Fix: Use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: instead
    // of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: alone. The new method
    // ensures you won't get a nil cell and, thus, crashing your app.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Grab your data here
    NSString *theTitle = imageNameArray[indexPath.row];

    // And set the title of your cell
    cell.textLabel.text = theTitle;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had not used your imageNameArray anywhere in the cellForRowAt of tableView this is why your data is not being displayed. You dequeued tableView correctly but hadn't given any data to display.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    CellLabel = (UILabel*) [ cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];       
    CellLabel = [imageNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

And if you are using a default tableView
then you can insert

```
cell.textLabel.text = [imageNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use titleForHeaderInSection in your tableview :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Your tittle here" }
```

Comment: Sorry, it's objective C. Forgot to say that.

Comment: The header title is not the same as the cell title.